# How to use ID from a table and send it to php file for query

Tags: javascript, php

So I've this admin-dashboard where I want to click on the options link which will take me to another page or show a modal of that particular person's details.
So basically, I want to get the ID of one particular person and send it to backend for query and display the details.

[image]

My doctor-details.php file

```
<?php

require('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM doctor";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0){
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['id'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['f_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['l_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['email'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['contact_number'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['gender'];?></td>
            <td><a href=""> Options</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php


    }
}
?>
```

my ajax code for doctor's details

```
//For Doctor
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#load-doctor-data").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'views/admin/doctor-details.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result){
                    $("#response-doctor").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });



    //Hide table on login
    $("#show-doctor-details").hide();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("#load-doctor-data").click(function(){
            $("#show-doctor-details").show();
            $("#show-patient-details").hide();
          });
    });
```

Comment: Where is your ``#load-doctor-data`` element? Kindly add that part also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var trs = document.getElementById('response-doctor').querySelectorAll('tr');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    var tds = trs[i].querySelectorAll('td');
    tds[tds.length-1].querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', '/user/'+tds[0].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

My bad, this sloution more easier (inside doctor-details.php):

```
<td><a href="/user/<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"> Options</a></td>
```

Comment: Hope its help you

Answer (score -1):

You can make entire table row as link
For example:

```
<tr a="profile.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'?];">
    ...
<tr>
```

This is how you can add link on every row which leads you to profile.php file where you can show personal information. When you are in profile.php you can access person's id with $_GET['id'] and fetch data from database using this id. If you are looking for more detailed answer don't hesitate to ask.